# make scroll view glitch in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

so i was making a scroll view in my app so i can have more content showing in one view. the storyboard has a lot of text, 1 picture, and 3 buttons at the end. every time i scroll all the way to the button and click on one of them it takes me to the corresponding storyboard but than when i click the button to go back to the main storyboard with all the content, it doesn't led me scroll back to the top. this is all the code in the .m file for the scroll view:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[myScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[myScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 940)];
}
```

this is the code in the .h file for the scroll view:

```
@interface SimplifyingNumericlaExpressionsViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScroll;

@end
```

is there any way i coud set the default coordinates of  the scroll view of when it is being view? or something that can fox that?

herei s the link of a video showing the problem http://youtu.be/TgTaiEEhPhc

any idea or example counts. im a beginner :(

thanks!

**UPDATE**

i tried putting the same code i had in the viewDidLoad and this is what happen:

http://youtu.be/R6M4gGyLxgQ

im now having a different problem, it doesn't scroll all the way down and even though i tried changing the values it still doesn't work. any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the things you are doing should be done in viewDidLoad not viewDidAppear. I would assume the bug is comming from the fact your scroll view was super low already when you set the content size possibly reanchoring your scrollView lower?

Comment: i tried doing the same code: [myScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[myScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 940)]; but it will not work on the viewDidload

Comment: i tried doing the the vieDidLoad but it doenst work. im not able to scroll all the way down http://youtu.be/R6M4gGyLxgQ